# How to make users auto update application using google play store

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

I am working in a small organization where we develop our own applications to be used by our own employees in the field. Already 150 employees installed our application in their tablets from SDcard.

We realized some changes required so we developed another version of our application.Now we want application to be updated automatically .So I uploaded the updated application in google play store and  set the device's google play store auto update setting to "**update apps any time. data charges may apply**". Now when i searched the application name in device's google play store i am able to see the application with **Update** button but my application is not getting updated automatically in my tablet,not even showing in the updates available list.

Can anyone suggest what i need to do so that my application will get updated in all 150 tablet automatically.

Did google changed any security setting for which my application is not getting updated automatically.

**Note : My application is a hybrid application developed using Cordova**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that Google Play won't automatically update an application initially installed from other sources. There is nothing you can really do about it but install it manually from Google Play.

Comment: thanxx for your comment @Anton Tarasov . Actually i tested this  in my tablet and it is got updated automatically but in other tablets it is not happening..The difference between these tablets are mine is a older one but other tablets are newer one (Android 5.0.1). So I need to know is there any security changes in google play store for new versions

Answer (score 0):

Google Play not allow.
But You can check from your server and show message request user updated.